# Show the Marker at the center of the circumcircles

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I am trying to draw few **circles within circle** and show them on the Google maps. And current location should be at the center of all the circles. Means in the middle of the circle.

Everything is working fine. But somehow my marker is not getting displayed at the center of all the circles. Marker size is `36 by 36`.

I tried few hit and trials but still the same problem. Is there any way I can place the marker at the center of all the circumcircles? What is the problem with my code because of that it is not showing in the center of circle? May be the way I am drawing circle is not right?

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
            (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

        mapController.animateTo(point);
        mapController.setZoom(15);

        if (mapOverlay == null) {
            mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(this, R.drawable.mark_blue);

            List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
        }

        mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
        mapView.invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Below is my MapOverlay class in which I am drawing circle within circle

```
class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
    private GeoPoint pointToDraw;
    int[] imageNames = new int[6];
    private Point mScreenPoints;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Paint mCirclePaint;

    public MapOverlay(GPSLocationListener gpsLocationListener, int currentUser) {
        imageNames[0] = currentUser;
        imageNames[1] = R.drawable.tenm;
        imageNames[2] = R.drawable.twentym;
        imageNames[3] = R.drawable.thirtym;
        imageNames[4] = R.drawable.fourtym;
        imageNames[5] = R.drawable.fiftym;

        mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(0x10000000);
        mCirclePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageNames[0]);
        mScreenPoints = new Point();
    }

    public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
        pointToDraw = point;
    }

    public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
        return pointToDraw;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        mScreenPoints = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, mScreenPoints);

        int totalCircle = 5;
        int radius = 40;
        int centerimagesize = 13;

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalCircle; i++) {
        canvas.drawCircle(mScreenPoints.x, mScreenPoints.y, i * radius, mCirclePaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageNames[i]),
            ((mScreenPoints.x) + (i * radius)), (mScreenPoints.y), null);
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, (mScreenPoints.x - (centerimagesize / 2)),
            (mScreenPoints.y - (centerimagesize / 2)), null);
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        return true;
        }
    }
```

Below is the screenshot from my communicator as well in which you can clearly see, it is not coming in the center of circle-

[image]

Can anyone provide some thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the top-left corner of the marker graphic is in the centre of the circle.  So you need to adjust the marker position by the displacement from the top-left corner to the actual point of the marker.  I guess that would be 18 horizontally and 36 vertically.

Comment: Thanks David for the suggestion. Can you tell me how and where shoud I add your mathematics in my code? I am not sure about that? Can you help me with that?

Comment: Somewhere around the line that has `canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, ...` - but can you tell me why you have `int centerimagesize = 13;`?  That seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: Thanks David for the suggestion. `centerimagesize =13` I have just put that in a random thought. No such logic behind that. And other thing, I have two `canvas.drawBitmap....` line where should I add that. And most importantly I am confuse how I am going to add that 18 and 36 as you mentioned in your answer. Little bit confused here with the syntax that I am supposed to use.

Comment: Can you tell me one more thing. How you came to these two numbers 18 horizontally and 36 vertically? What sort of logic you used here? From the learning experience I wanted to know.

Comment: Well, you said that the marker image was 36 x 36, right?  So it seems to me that it would be 18 horizontally from the left side to the centre, and 36 from the top to the point of the marker.